# Nested n:m + attributes JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, mapping

I have a strange need in a project. Joining two n:m+attributes table (I will present the behavior with dummy attributes).

1. FirstTable (idPlace, idAddress,idSchool, wage) joined 1:m;
2. SecondTable (idPlace, idAddress,idSchool, qty, idEnterprise)

EDIT (example schema):
[image]

Of course that I have the tables Place, Address, School, Enterprise with theirs respective Ids, gets, sets and attributes implemented in the entity classes.

**CODE:**

**Place**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Place")
public class Place implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idLine")
private Long idLine;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.place")
private List<FirstTable> firstTables;
}
```

**Address**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Address")
public class Address implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idAddress")
private Long idAddress;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.address")
private List<FirstTable> firstTables;
}
```

**School**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "School")
public class School implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idSchool")
private Long idSchool;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.school")
private List<FirstTable> firstTables;
}
```

**FirstTable**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FirstTable")
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.school", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idSchool")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.address", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idAddress")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.place", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idPlace")) })
public class FirstTable implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
protected FirstTablePK pk = new FirstTablePK();
 }
```

**FirstTablePK**

```
@Embeddable
public class FirstTablePK implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@ManyToOne
private Address address;
@ManyToOne 
private Place place;
@ManyToOne 
private School school;
}
```

The above mentioned tables and joins are working perfectly. Now I want to join the FirstTable with the Second Table.

**Enterprise**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Enterprise")
public class Enterprise implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "idEnterprise")
private Long idEnterprise;
```

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "pk.enterprise")
   private List secondTables;
   }

Now for the SecondTable I've followed the same logic to connect to the Enterprise. For connecting with the FirstTable I've tried this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SecondTable")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.firstTable", joinTable = @JoinTable(
                name = "FirstTable", inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "idSchool", referencedColumnName = "idSchool"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "idAddress", referencedColumnName = "idAddress"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "idPlace", referencedColumnName = "idPlace") })),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.enterprise", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEnterprise")) })
public class SecondTable implements Serializable{}
```

Something is not working in my annotation, I'm trying to do an inverseJoin to the FirstTable table. The compilation shows this error:

```
"org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A component cannot hold properties split into 2 different tables"
```

I've tried to provide a MV example.
Thanks in advance and I really need your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hours later and many tries before I've managed to solve the problem. Actually the solution was much simpler that I was thinking initially.

Here it is:

```
 @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.firstTable", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "idSchool"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "idAddress"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "idPlace") }),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.enterprise", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "idEnterprise")) })
```